# Overlay text using FFmpeg command in android programmatically

Tags: android, ffmpeg

I need to know what is the issue with my FFmpeg command for overlaying text to a video in android.

```
 command = new String[]{"ffmpeg", "-i",  original_path,  "-vf", "drawtext=text='SiteName.local': fontsize=18: fontcolor=white: x=10:y=h-th-10", "-acodec", "copy", "-y",  dest.getAbsolutePath()};
```

I am trying to create a video with a text overlay. However, i'm getting an error

```
 [NULL @ 0xea699600] Unable to find a suitable output format for 'ffmpeg'
    ffmpeg: Invalid argument
```

I have tested for the input file and output file using different command for trimming videos and it worked. However, the FFmpeg command for overlaying text does not work. I kindly ask for help.

Besides, i also need to know how i can animate the text to scroll from left to right, bounce using FFmpeg commands in android etc

Answer (score 0):

Finally i managed solving the issue over a long search. Drawtext can't work without including the fontfile. So the below code is what managed to settle my scores

```
command = new String[]{"-i",  original_path,  "-vf", "drawtext=fontfile=/system/fonts/DroidSans.ttf:text='SiteName hulluway':fontsize=40:fontcolor=black: x=w-(t-4.5)*(w+tw)/5.5:y=100", "-acodec", "copy", "-y",  dest.getAbsolutePath()};
```

Answer (score 0):

this code worked, text adds overly on video using FFmpeg

```
command = new String[]{"ffmpeg", "-i",  videoPath,  "-vf", "drawtext=fontfile=path/your_font.ttf:text='your_text': fontsize=18: fontcolor=white:x=(w-text_w)/2:y=h-line_h", "-c:a", "copy",outputPath};
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).